# Main window Textbox acces from class in other file

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

so I have a main window it has lots of other window instance in it

```
MainWindow
{
    Window1 win1= new Window1();
    Window2 win2 = new Window2();
    // ....... and so on 

    private keydownevent(  ,key e)
    {  
        if(e.keu==key.return)
        {
            //some logic here
            if(some condition)
            {
                win1.show();
            }
            else if(some condition)
           {
                win2.show()
           }
           // ....
        }
    }
}
// and in window1 lets say 
Window1
{
    foo_class fcl = new foo_class();
    click_button()
    {
        // do some logic
        fc1.function in class;
    }
 }
```

now textbox content are a barcode and i want to clear textbox in MainWindow when window1 is showed and click_button in window 1 is done

//////////
i have tried

```
          MainWindow win= (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
             win.txtBlock1.Text = "";
```

putting in foo_class as well as in button_click but it throws error window1 can not be cast to mainwindow

i also tried

creating  a constructor that takes argument as textbox in keydown function as window(texbox) but that willl create a new instance every tim but i want only want on instance created while instantiating mainwindow and keep using that window1 instance

PLease suggest some method that work in clearing textbox in main window ? and where should i put that method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating the `Window`s, you could set the `Owner` to `this`. i.e.:

```
public class MainWindow
{
    Window1 win1 = new Window1();
    Window2 win2 = new Window2();

    ...

    //in code, before call Show() on win1 or win2
    //set win1/win2.Owner = this;
}
```

Then when you ned to clear the parent you could get a reference to the parent by simply calling `((MainWindow)this.Owner).txtBlock1.Text = "";`.

This is all on the assumption that `Window1` and `Window2` are actually subclasses of `Window`, or you actually meant to declare `win1` and `win2` as Window.

EDIT:

As mentioned in the comments, an alternative would be to supply a reference to an instance of `MainWindow` to the constructors of `win1` and `win2` if they are subclasses of window via a new constructor.

I'd also recommend that you should create a new method on `MainWindow` called `ClearText` so you don't have to expose the text box name.

Comment: no i actually meant to declare win1 and win2 as they are displayed , there are buttons on it which call some class and use function in it and they are created only once along with creation on mainwindow  and they are never closed unless you close the whole application i.e. mainwindow   . i am sorry i am just new to WPF is there nay diference in subclass of window or what i am doing ?  :(  all window1 window 2 and so on  have public partial class Window 1 : Window in them

Comment: Your comment doesn't address whether the above code works or not, and I'm afraid I don't really understand it.

Comment: above code throws XMLPARSEREXCEPTION
message Cannot set Owner property to a Window that has not been shown previously.
public partial class:window
{window1 win1 = new window()}

public MainWindow()
{
Initalizecomponenet();
win1.Owner = this;
}

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.owner.aspx. You may need to move the `Owner` property assignment to the point just before you show `win1` and `win2` - i.e. after the `MainWindow` has been shown.

Comment: it works thanks  one last question
does it affect current program in anyway i mean creating additional instance or like that or it is just a inheretance knid of declrataion

Comment: only drawback is when owned window is made invisible Owner window also goes to back and other  running application comes to top

Comment: If that is an issue then you could create a constructor on the `Window1` and `Window2` classes that accept a `MainWindow` instance as a parameter. That way you have a reference to `MainWindow` and can clear the text box that way.